# Golang: Executing a command with its arguments

Tags: git, go, command-line, command

I'm trying to execute a command using go.

```
executableCommand := strings.Split("git commit -m 'hello world'", " ")
executeCommand(executableCommand[0], executableCommand[1:]...)
cmd := exec.Command(command, args...)
```

But here is what I get

```
error: pathspec 'world"' did not match any file(s) known to git.
exit status 1
```

This is because `-m` gets `'hello` only and not `'hello world'` since the command line is split using `" "`.

Any idea to make it work?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What you want is actually hard to achieve without help of shell that interprets quotes etc. So you may use shell to run your command.

```
exec.Command("sh", "-c", "echo '1 2 3'")
```

Comment: Such a simple solution! Is there an equivalently simple solution for Windows?

Comment: Keep in mind doing something like this can make your program more vulnerable to command injection vulnerabilities

Answer (score 3):

What about to escape the quotes, then use the [strconv.Unquote](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Unquote) function?

```
executableCommand := strings.Split(strconv.Unquote("git commit -m \"hello world\"", " "))
executeCommand(executableCommand[0], executableCommand[1:]...)
cmd := exec.Command(command, args...)
```

Of course this will vary of how shell will interpret quotes.

Here is short demonstration:

https://play.golang.org/p/V6uqWcczGV